# What is the use of Pointer to an array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

What is the use of having pointer to an array when we can have single array of pointer.

```
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {20,30,40,50,60,70};
    int (*ptr)[6] = &arr;
    int *prtarr[1] = { arr };

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); i++)
    {
        cout << arr[i] << endl;     
        cout << ptr[0][i] << endl;
        cout << prtarr[0][i] << endl;
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

instead of using pointer to an array we can use size 1 array and same result is expected.

Comment: Write a function that accepts an argument of type `int(*)[6]`.   Passing `&arr` or `ptr` to it will compile.  Passing `prtarr` to it will not.

Comment: you are mixing up things here: `int (*ptr)[6] = &arr;` is a **pointer to an array** of size 6. `int *prtarr[1] = { arr };` is an **array of pointers** of size 1.

Comment: How do you get size 6 from `int *prtarr[1]` ?

Comment: Size of array and pointer is different

Comment: But the usage I didn't understand properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One most common use for pointer to array is when you want to pass a multidimensional array (actually pointer to an element of the multidimensional array) then pointer to array is used

```
void multd_array_func(int (*arr)[6]);
```

From another function this function can be called as

```
int arr[] = {20,30,40,50,60,70};
multd_array_func(&arr);
```

This can't be done with just a pointer. In the above function passing `arr` or `prtarr[0]` will not work. They are incompatible pointer types with `int (*)[6]`.

You can see the difference between `arr`, `*ptr` and `ptrarr[0]` by printing the size

```
printf("%zu %zu %zu", sizeof(arr), sizeof(ptrarr[0]), sizeof(*ptr));
```

This will print

```
12 8 12
```